# What does it mean to make run through the tape?

Tags: translation

What does it mean when someone says to " run through the tape"

Comment: Can we have some context, please?

Answer (score 2):

I can see three meanings here.

1. In athletics, competitors race towards, and run through, a tape at the finishing line.
2. One can run through audio tape or video tape, searching for something on it.
3. I don't think it is much used, colloquially, but I am sure I have heard the phrase used metaphorically in the sense of urging someone to new levels of achievement. 'Leading up to the exams he was making me run through the tape,' meaning he not only wanted me to reach the tape but to run through it. Get as high a mark as possible, that is, not just pass the exam.

Yes, I have found a reference :

> https://www.dailykos.com/stories/2008/10/9/625260/-
>
> we not only want Barack to win but we want to encourage people in the future to be involved

Comment: ok, deleted comment